# Docker compose GrayLog

Tags: docker-compose, graylog

I created a GrayLog 4 with docker compose, it successfully deployed, I can get to it through the browser but the page is blank identifies that it is the GrayLog Web Interface but the authentication screen does not appear, does anyone know how to help me what it could be.

```
    version: '3'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:4.2
  # Elasticsearch: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/docker.html
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:7.10.2
    environment:
      - http.host=0.0.0.0
      - transport.host=localhost
      - network.host=0.0.0.0
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 1g
  # Graylog: https://hub.docker.com/r/graylog/graylog/
  graylog:
    image: graylog/graylog:4.0
    environment:
      # CHANGE ME (must be at least 16 characters)!
      - GRAYLOG_PASSWORD_SECRET=somepasswordpepper
      # Password: admin
      - GRAYLOG_ROOT_PASSWORD_SHA2=8c6976e5b5410415bde908bd4dee15dfb167a9c873fc4bb8a81f6f2ab448a918
      - GRAYLOG_HTTP_EXTERNAL_URI=http://127.0.0.1:9000/
    entrypoint: /usr/bin/tini -- wait-for-it elasticsearch:9200 --  /docker-entrypoint.sh
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mongo
      - elasticsearch
    ports:
      # Graylog web interface and REST API
      - 9000:9000
      # Syslog TCP
      - 1514:1514
      # Syslog UDP
      - 1514:1514/udp
      # GELF TCP
      - 12201:12201
      # GELF UDP
      - 12201:12201/udp
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5Edw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your screenshot the IP address ends in a 6, but Graylog is bouund to 127.0.0.1. Set http_bind to 127.0.0.1 and http_publish or http_external to the interface IP that ends in 6.

ref: [Graylog docs](https://docs.graylog.org/docs/docker)